# Kafka consumer consuming with special characters appended to both key and value

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

kafka consumer consuming messages with Special characters appended to both the key and value. consumer is consuming with the below properties

```
enable.auto.commit=true
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
bootstrap.servers={hostname}:9092
group.id=JUNIQ
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

We are using the key/value deserializers as shown above and the messages consumed are like below

Consumed message from topic [FT-Toc-V3] with offset [42734] partition [1] data [key 882398999998492^@, value SI,09-APR-21 3702,10020,3551,301990027,1,0:60203:314542;,1^@]

Please notice the key and value ending with "^@", Is there any specific reason why it is consuming like that, please let me know what is causing this and happens in linux environments precisely.

Thanks in advance.Is it because of some encoding or any properties?

Comment: How is the message in the topic? Have you checked what your publisher is publishing to it? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @JorgeCampo- Thanks for the comment, I have asked the concerned team to check that first and also wanted to know if there is also any chance of encoding issue between producer and consumer in kafka.

Comment: I've been working with Kafka and this same deserializer and never saw this happening before. What you could also do on your side is try to debug the consumer before it deserialize the message then you will know